# How to make own tag system in php like Wapka

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to php and I need a function to do this.

This is user input:

```
<tr>
<td width="23%" align="left" valign="top" margin="auto">
<img src="%thumb%" title="%name%" name="%name%" alt="%name%" width="65" height="56" style="border-radius:2px;"/>
<br/></td><td align="left">
<a href="/download/%id%/:SLUG(%name%);"><b>%name%.%format%</b></a>
<br/><b><font color="gold">Size:</font></b> 
%size%<br/><b><font color="gold">Upload at: </font> 
</b> :VALUE(%date%).DATE(AGO);</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left">
<div style="background:#444;border-top: 1px solid #505050;padding:3px 0px 3px 6px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;"><font color="gold"><b>
 Category:</b> </font> <a href="/category/%dir%/:SLUG(%dirname%);" style="color:#ddd"><b>%dirname%</b></a> </div></td></tr>
```

I need to change %name% to $data['name'] and %thumb% to $data['thumb'] and like so , where $data has fetched data from database.

I am creating a web builder like Wapka, The above code is user input and I will save that encoded to database but when I will show that html in website as decoded all the tags like %name%,%thumb% etc show fetched data from MySQL in php page through mysqli_fetch_array in a while loop.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php altough i have no idea what you want to do, this will help you if you want to literally change the data in a string.
Maybe tell a bit more what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_replace_callback function to achieve that kind of behaviour.

```
    <?php

    $string = '%name%.%format%
      Size: %size%
      Upload at: :VALUE(%date%).DATE(AGO); Category: %dirname%';
    $data = [
        'name' => 'Samsung',
        'date' => '22.02.22',
    ];
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/%(.*?)%/', function($matches) use ($data) {
        return $data[$matches[1]] ?? ''; // value or empty
    }, $string);

    var_dump($string);
```

Basically what it does is looking for `%something%` pattern and replaces with `$data['something']` value

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php